# Number of good permutations are greater than bad permutations

Tags: proof-writing, permutations

Take a permutation of $(x_1,x_2....x_{2n})$ of the set $[2n]$. A permutation is said to be a good permutation if $$\exists i~~ |x_i - x_{i+1}| = n$$ otherwise it is a bad permutation. Now we need to show number of good permutations are greater than number of bad permutations.

I didn't get any idea. Can someone help me with it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Permutation on a set from $\{1, 2, \ldots, 2n\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68496/permutation-on-a-set-from-1-2-ldots-2n)

Comment: Yes, it answered my question, Thank you